# Why I can't install this old WordPRess website on my local webserver?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, content-management-system

I am pretty new to WP (I came from Joomla) and I am finding some difficulties trying to put on my local web server an old backup of a website (made using WP 3.5)

I have performed the following operation:

1) I have put the website backup into a directory named **blog** into my Apache **www** directory on my Ubuntu local system.

2) Then I have put the database backup on my MySql local server

3) Finally I have change the values in the **wp-config.php** file to use my local DB

The problem is that when I try to open the URL to see the website I see noting (a white screen)

Into the Apache log file (/var/log/apache2/error.log) I found the following errors messages:

```
[Fri Jan 10 22:04:50 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 10 22:05:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:05:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:37 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:37 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:38 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:38 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:39 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:39 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:40 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
[Fri Jan 10 22:38:40 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 12
```

Why? what could be the problem? How can I try to solve it?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: The error is clear, it can't load file `/var/www/blog/wp-load.php`. Probably the problem is in the `include_path` of php.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure within the database the url structures has been same. It looks like some file is missing or the path structure is not proper.

Comment: mmm and into the DB what exactly I have to check?

Comment: Check prefix_options table and the siteurl field

Comment: I have not a prefix_options table (it is an old WP, the 3.5 maybe this table did not exist in this version)

Comment: This table exist in all versions. is there no table named wp_options?

Comment: Yes wp_option exist, if you see the other response I have tryed also to change the values of the home and siteurl fields setting them to http://localhost/blog but don't work, do you have some idea?